# HTML CSS awkward table styling - highlighting single TD with border colour

Tags: javascript, css-tables

For the life of me I cannot seem to figure this out. It seems like a simple thing to do but html tables can be so rebellious.

This is what I'm trying to do -

```
.highlight {border-color:red;}
```

[image]

Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/MuAR4/1/

See that there's gaps missing from box 2, I'm wanting the border to go all the way around with no breaks. The highlight class should also be able to be applied to any other box which all have their own problems.

This is a selected state for when the user clicks on a box, handled by javascript.

Is this even possible? I'm open to using Javascript hacks if necessary.

**update** I'm wanting this to work in IE7, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: you are collapsing the borders.. how can the browser know which of the two borders to use (*red or grey*) for a shared edge ? I mean, if you put a green border for `box 1` what color should the edge on its right be ? (*red or green ?*)

Comment: I need a 5px border all around, is there anything else you'd recommend? even between cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get creative with background color and border-spacing with a little help from outline like so (note that borders should not be collapsed):

```
table {
  background: #555;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
td {
  background: white;
  width:175px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.highlight {
   outline: 5px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MuAR4/9/

Comment: Thanks, that's very close to what I want, but unfortunately ie doesn't support border-spacing. any workarounds?

Comment: used cellspacing=5 in ie7, but now I have an issue with highlighting the td.

Comment: IE7 doesn't support the outline property (and wasn't mentioned as a requirement), but IE8 does.  Your only option at this point is with JavaScript (and outside my realm of expertise).

Answer (score 1):

your table don't need an extra border an you can use separate: http://jsfiddle.net/MuAR4/3/

```
table, td {border:5px solid #555; border-collapse:separate;}
table {border: 0px;}
td {width:175px; vertical-align:top;}
.highlight {border-color:red;}
```

Comment: unfortunately the design is quite strict. I need a 5px border everywhere, no more or less. Plus there's an extra black border around the red, sorry, I know it's a pain.

Comment: i don't understand it completly. you need 10px around the highlighted td? so remove the line with table {border: 0px;} . then you have 5px red and 5 pixel gray.

Comment: I need 5px red around the highlighted td, then 5px grey everywhere else.

Comment: Please see edited question with image of what I'm trying to achieve.